# Can't call forms & classes, Can't use Properties.Settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, syntax-error, reinstall

The last 2 days Visual studio is doing weird I already reinstalled it and it didn't fix my problems.

I can't call other classes or forms :

Class :
http://snag.gy/7W4dl.jpg

Form:
http://snag.gy/lfm8Y.jpg

It doesn't let me use Properties.Settings :
http://snag.gy/W3VJn.jpg

Code open mods form :

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mods modsForm = new Mods();
    modsForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Code using Properties.Settings and calling class things

```
if (SAVE_UN_CHECK.Checked)
{
    if (SAVE_UN_CHECK.Text != "")
    {
        string clearText = SAVE_UN_CHECK.Text.Trim();
        string cipherText = CryptorEngine.Encrypt(clearText, true);

        //Save textbox text to file
        Properties.Settings.Default.USER_USERNAME = cipherText;
        USERNAME_TEXT.Text = cipherText;
    }
}
```

What to do? I never had these weird errors.
I already reinstalled Visual Studio 2012 and all its other stuff like SQL Server stuff.
But it didn't fix the problem.

These are the using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Comment: Do you have the correct using statements in the top of your file ?

Comment: I wish whenever my code didn't compile I could simply reinstall Visual Studio to fix it.

Comment: There are probably missing references.

Comment: Check the ErrorList of VS for Errors and Warnings. Close solution+VS, delete all bin and obj folders of your solution. then open VS+solution again and to a build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a reference to the dll that has `CryptorEngine`  and `Mods` types. Right-click on the project and select `Add Reference...`.

You then have to make sure the `using` statement at the top of the file points to the namespace where `CryptorEngine` and `Mods` are defined.

Comment: Yeah that fixed one of the problems :D thanks.

Comment: Thanks it fixed all the stuff. Now I know that I need to Reference them :D thanks!(ありがと！)